# Configurable Governance Artifacts (RXT): expansion or composition

Tags: wso2

I'm creating Configurable Governance Artifacts on WSO2 Governance Registry.

The Registry Extension File supports relationships between artifacts but I'd like to expand or compose them. For example, I need to define an artifact which **has** other objects . And also I'd like to define an artifact with some fields, and expand it with other fields.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear about your requirement did you go through the documentation [here](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=22185121)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can expand the existing rxt as your wish..
What you have to do is, open the stored RXT file, and new fields there and restart the server..
Go to management console-->view the rxt file, you will see the newly added fields..